# How to display count of rows based on a particular value in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am looking for a solution to display number of rows based on a particular column data using CodeIgniter.

This is basically for a Shop registration project. I have a database table named `shopowner` with a column named `status`. and this `status` column have only 3 values. ie. if status is `0` then the record is waiting for approval, once approved the status will become `1` and `2` for rejection. Now in my Dashboard I need to display total number of pending, Approved and Rejected records. Can any one help me out with this and please tell me what to add in Model, Controller and view. I am totally new to CodeIgniter. Thanks in advance.

### Model

```php
public function count_rows($status)
    {
        $this->db->select('status, COUNT(status) as total');
        $this->db->group_by('status', $status);  
        $this->db->get('shopowner');
    }
```

Expected output would be like

Total Registration : 4
Pending Approval : 2
Approved : 1
Rejected : 1

Comment: its look right to me just return the value return $this->db->get('showowner')->result();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all statistics in one query, u can use following code

```
 $this->db->select('status, COUNT(status) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('status');  
 $this->db->get('shopowner');
```

But if u want to get a spesific status count,  u have to add your status code into where parametr

```
$this->db->where(['status' => $status]);
$result = $this->db->get('shopowner');
echo $result->num_rows();
```

I hope this will help u)

```
private function count_rows($status) {
    $this->db->where(['status' => $status]);
    return $this->db->get('shopowner')->num_rows();
}
```

In your controller

```
    $data = [
        'pending_approval' => $this->count_rows(4),
        'approved' => $this->count_rows(2),
        'rejected' => $this->count_rows(1)
    ];
    $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

You can use `<?=$approved?>` to call $data items

Comment: Thanks Farhad for the your help. If I choose the second option here how can I pass this parameter to controller then view it as Total count when status=0 | status=1 | status=2

Answer (score 0):

There no need to give 'status' column at first line of code, only use '$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as total');' at first line and use where clause with status column instead of 'status' column using in 'group_by' clause. Can you try following code:

```
public function count_rows($status)
{
    $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as total');
    $this->db->from('shopowner');
    $this->db->where('status', $status);
    $this->db->group_by('status');  
    $this->db->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a database table named `shopowner` with 4 columns named: `id`, `name`, `status`, `type_name`. The status column has only 3 types of values which is like you described. If status is 0 then the record is waiting for approval, once approved the status will become 1 and 2 for rejection. `type_name` shows reject approved and waiting in it, and `type_name` have name type like reject approved or waiting, `id` is autogenerated, and name is customer name.

**model**

```
$this->db->select('type_name, COUNT(status) as star ');
$this->db->from('shopowner');
$this->db->group_by('status');
```

**controller**

```
$data['user']=$this->your_model->name();
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

**view**

```
<table>
  <tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>total</th>
</tr>
    <?php foreach( $user as $users ){
        ?>
     <tr>
    <td><?php echo $users->type_name?></td>
    <td><?php echo $users->star?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
```